# How did the first angel get to Manhattan?

Tags: doctor-who, weeping-angels

How did the first Weeping Angel get into Manhattan? Clearly it wasn't destroyed by the paradox, so it seems at least one survived. If there is no way to know exactly how, what methods does it have available?

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't able to find any official comments on whether or not the angels themselves have the ability to travel through time and/or space.

Comment: I am tad annoyed that this episode implied that the angels actually inhabit *existing* statues, as opposed to *being* statues...

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Did it?

Comment: @Pureferret yes, at one point The Doctor says something like "they've taken over every statue in the city"; beyond that, at least two of the angels were famous statues that have been in NYC for decades and are still there even after the angels were destroyed.

Comment: Yes, that episode is reason for quite some frustration where the angels are concerned. For instance when inside the "farm" building they are in a narrow corridor with angels approaching from both ends and the angels are not moving backwards. They should have deadlocked just as they did in Blink. There are Babyangels which "only" send you some other place not some other time but apparently angels can take over statues as well, even those made of copper, not stone. And as we know from Ghostbusters, people notice and see (!) the statue of liberty moving across town!

Comment: @user1129682: Ghostbusters has taught us so many things.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: It did. Aren't we all afraid to cross streams? :D

Comment: @user1129682: everyone I know has never crossed the streams, and everyone I know is alive. QED.

Answer (score 3):

As The Doctor mentions, its a lone survivor. A weak one, possibly dying soon since its out of energy. It was probably attracted to the energy field of the Tardis, and came to the graveyard to hopefully harvest a little energy before it died.

> River: Where the hell did that come from? 
>
>  The Doctor: It's a survivor. Very weak, but keep your eyes on it. 
>
>  Amy: Where's Rory?
>
>  The Doctor: I'm sorry. Amelia. I'm so, so sorry. 
>
>  Amy: No. No we can just go and get him in the TARDIS. One more paradox. 
>
>  The Doctor: Would rip New York apart. 
>
>  Amy: No, that's not true. I don't believe you. 
>
>  River: Mother, it's true.

Also, considering it is a race of Weeping Angels, and not just (say) a family (like the Slytheen), its likely that there were many many others present throughout time and space, that were not destroyed since they were not directly involved in the Paradox.

Even considering they were destroyed, we know that the "image of an angel, is a an angel itself". A fact that was known to very few people (The Doctor also only just found it out after being alive and kicking for over a thousand years). Therefore it could have been created by a simple pictorial/video reproduction of the same.

Basically, there are many many ways, that the first weeping angel could have come to Manhattan.